# TEA Encryption with C#

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm trying to work with a TEA encryption algorithm developed using [VB.NET](http://web.archive.org/web/20111104141040/http://www.blog-dotnet.com/post/Tiny-Encryption-Algorithm-%28TEA%29-in-Visual-BasicNET.aspx) (the only .NET implementation I found) in a C# project and get an exception (System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow)

So I wondered if there is some C# implementation for TEA (couldn't find any).

The encoding/decoding is on QueryString parameters - so it should be used on strings and not Ints.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I looked at your vb version and the original version and they are different -- for example you have the line  `sum += delta` before the other calculations in the loop.  In the original it is the 2nd of the 3 assignments.  I'd say make your version functionally the same and the error will go away.

Comment: I needed an easy to implement encryption with fast operation. I don't need high encryption abilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article you provided actually links to a C# CodeProject article that the TEA implementation came from: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6137/Tiny-Encryption-Algorithm-TEA-for-the-Compact-Fram

If you're still having issues, could you post your source?

Comment: They also have bugs (like if the string is not 4-multiples length). very annoying.

Comment: Note that the algorithm as implemented in that article is *incorrect* as per http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/1592947/Major-Flaw-in-the-algorythm-modified.aspx - the supplied algorithm passes 2 bytes (16 bits) to the encoding method, when it should be passing 8 bytes.

Comment: Additionally, the `code()`/`decode()` routines in that article actually implement the **X** TEA algorithm, not the original TEA. I have already notified CodeProject about these issues, but I fear the article will remain uncorrected and misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the code into an [unchecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8%28VS.71%29.aspx) block to suppress the overflow exceptions (and just let the operations overflow as they would in C and Java).

Comment: Tried it - when i put an unchecked block on the c# code it doesn't effect the VB.NET code, and as it seems there is no unchecked block in vb.net

Comment: found it under compile options - now getting another exception: System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte